# PHP curl strange behavior PUT vs. POST

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

One of my projects contains an interface to a web based database, which I call using curl.
A curl with -X PUT will create a new record, a curl with -X POST will update an existing record.
If I perform this using Advanced REST Client, it works as it should.
If I try this using a call of **curl_exec** out of my PHP script, the POST works but the PUT fails.
'Fails' means, I get a http 100 as response instead a 200 or 400.

```
$strXML = "<XML></XML>"; //valid XML here
$cURL = "https://www.webURL.here";
$cToken = "this_is_my_very_secret_token";
$ch = curl_init();

//POST

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_POST => true,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$strXML",
                CURLOPT_URL => $cURL,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("X-Auth-Token: $cToken","Content-Type:text/xml"),
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
));
$strXMLEvents = curl_exec($ch);
```

The PUT call looks similar:

```
// PUT
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                    CURLOPT_PUT => true,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$strXML",
                    CURLOPT_URL => $cURL,
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array("X-Auth-Token: $cToken","Content-Type:text/xml","Content-Length: ".strlen($strXML)),
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                    CURLOPT_VERBOSE     => true
));
$strXMLEvents = curl_exec($ch);
```

Since I encounter this on my developing system (a win 10 PC), I thought, this could be the reason. But after I deployed the code onto the Linux webserver, the behavior stays the same...

Since the transfer works "manually" with ARC, I suspect a bug in my script - but I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the manual:

> `CURLOPT_PUT`

> TRUE to HTTP PUT a file. The file to PUT must be set with CURLOPT_INFILE and CURLOPT_INFILESIZE.

since we are not putting a file, instead of `CURLOPT_PUT => true` try `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT"`

```
// PUT
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$strXML",
                    CURLOPT_URL => $cURL,
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array("X-Auth-Token: $cToken","Content-Type:text/xml" /* ,"Content-Length: ".strlen($strXML) */ ),
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                    CURLOPT_VERBOSE     => true
));
$strXMLEvents = curl_exec($ch);
```

This way we just change the HTTP verb from `POST` to `PUT`

Comment: OK, saw your answer as I had posted mine.
Basicly the same Idea ;-)

Comment: when using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, or using CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, do not set the Content-Length header manually, instead let curl auto-generate it for you. curl won't make any typos, and won't calculate the size wrong, but you may, so you shouldn't (when you don't have to). (you seem to incorrectly assume that curl won't make a Content-Length header automatically if absent; but curl will do that if you don't)

Answer (score 0):

I think, I got it!

Problem was, that I tried to send the content as a string.
As I send it as a file, it worked:

```
// PUT
$fXML=fopen($path2File,'r' ); // filestream with XML content
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                    CURLOPT_PUT => true,
                    CURLOPT_URL => $cURL,
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array("X-Auth-Token: $cToken","Content-Type:text/xml"),
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                    CURLOPT_VERBOSE     => true,
                    CURLOPT_INFILESIZE =>strlen($strXML),
                    CURLOPT_INFILE => $fXML
));
$strXMLEvents = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: don't use the `r` mode, it behaves differently when running on Windows, to make sure your code is both Windows and Linux compatible, you should use `rb` (with the `b` posfix, the code works the same in both Linux and Windows, but without the `b` , Windows may insert random `\r`-carriage-return bytes on every newline, while the same code running on Linux (or any other OS, really) doesn't.)